# Is it possible to get screen content from an Android Service

Tags: android, screenshot, android-tv

I am trying to create a TV back light controller that runs on Android TV. To do this I want to use what is being displayed and adjust the back light colors accordingly. I am having trouble determining a good way to basically get a screenshot regularly through a service. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

On Android 5.0+, you can use [the media projection APIs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/package-summary.html) for this. However:

- The user has to authorize this, by launching one of your activities which then displays a system-supplied authorization dialog
- That authorization does not last forever, but only for however long your process is around (and possibly less than that, though so far in my testing it seems to last as long as the process does)
- AFAIK, DRM-protected materials will be blocked from the screenshots, and so using those screenshots to try to detect foreground UI colors may prove unreliable

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in right direction. I was able to start a VirtualDisplay and use that in a background service that runs until it is shut off. On a phone it worked perfect but on a tv it does not display media content to the TV only to the VirtualDisplay.

Comment: Is there any other feasible way to achieve this ?

Comment: @OlsiSaqe: Achieve what?

Comment: I mean is there any api in place that would allow you to get some information about predominant color or color intensity currently displayed on screen without having to do a screenshot or even using the media projection api? I mean screenshots are really problematic in terms of sensitive content and would not be a suitable api for retrieving such a general information about the colors of the screen.

Comment: @OlsiSaqe: There is nothing like that, unless I am forgetting something. Sorry!